# Parsing Optional Tags in C#

Tags: c#, tags, option-type, selectnodes

I'm trying to find an easy and slick way to do the following requirement.

I have a XML message with this arrangement:

```
  <persons>
    <person>
       <firstName>Mike</firstName>
       <middleName>K.</middleName>
       <lastName>Kelly</lastName>
    </person>
    <person>
       <firstName>Steve</firstName>
       <lastName>David</lastName>
    </person>
    <person>
       <firstName>Laura</firstName>
       <middleName>X.</middleName>
       <lastName>Xavier</lastName>
    </person>
  </persons>
```

I want to parse this XML using xPath expressions.

```
persons/person/firstName
persons/person/middleName
persons/person/lastName
```

My objective is store firstName, middleName and lastName tag values like this into a list of string objects like this:

```
firstNameList[0] = "Mike";
firstNameList[1] = "Steve";
firstNameList[2] = "Laura";

middleNameList[0] = "K.";
middleNameList[1] = null;
middleNameList[2] = "X.";

lastNameList[0] = "Kelly";
lastNameList[1] = "David";
lastNameList[2] = "Xavier";
```

In my C# code, I do this:

```
XmlNodeList firstNameNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("persons/person/firstName", nsmgr);
XmlNodeList middleNameNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("persons/person/middleName", nsmgr);
XmlNodeList lastNameNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("persons/person/lastName", nsmgr);
```

The problem with this code is that for middle name, I don't have it for 2nd person in my XML list.  So the middleNameNodeList returns 2 values (K. and X.) but I wouldn't know whether the 1st or 2nd or 3rd person's middle name is missing.

I was hoping that SelectNodes() API would provide an iteration or index ID as which repeating element has a given value.

Please suggest me an easiest way to achieve what I needed?  Thanks so much for your help, JK

Comment: can you have <middleName /> for person with no middle name?

Comment: @StackOverflowException, that's a good thought.  In that case, would SelectNodes() return 3 values in this example? K., null and X.?  I need to experiment it.

Comment: yes. the second middleName won't be null but the `XmlNodeList`'s `InnerXml` would be blank. See my answer :)

Comment: Does this have to be a fragement? Could XmlSerializer and a declared type work for you?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
foreach (Node person in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("persons/person", nsmgr))
{
    firstNameNodeList.Add(person.SelectSingleNode("firstName", nsmgr));
    middleNameNodeList.Add(person.SelectSingleNode("middleName", nsmgr));
    lastNameNodeList.Add(person.SelectSingleNode("lastName", nsmgr));
}
```

Comment: I just given the sample XML to explain the point however in my real system, I would get a complex repeating tag elements with xpaths pre-defined.  So I wouldn't know the individual tag names, only the XPath expression. I want to go generic as possible.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @JKK: there is no guarentee that nodelists are ordered. You cannot assume that, let's say, 3rd elements from all nodelists belong to the same "person". So the above answer by Jollymorphic is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Intead of getting a list of names, try getting a list of `person`s, then iterate the list and get their names.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to iterate over `persons/person` and handle each individually - this would work:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(@"test.xml");
var persons = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("persons/person");
foreach (XmlNode person in persons)
{
    string firstName = person.SelectSingleNode("firstName").InnerText;
    string middleName = (person.SelectSingleNode("middleName") != null) 
                        ? person.SelectSingleNode("middleName").InnerText 
                        : null;
    string lastName = person.SelectSingleNode("lastName").InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   <persons>
    <person>
       <firstName>Mike</firstName>
       <middleName>K.</middleName>
       <lastName>Kelly</lastName>
    </person>
    <person>
       <firstName>Steve</firstName>
       <middleName /> 
       <lastName>David</lastName>
    </person>
    <person>
       <firstName>Laura</firstName>
       <middleName>X.</middleName>
       <lastName>Xavier</lastName>
    </person>
  </persons>

<person>
   <firstName>Steve</firstName>
   <middleName /> 
   <lastName>David</lastName>
</person>
```

this should return "K","","X" for `InnnerText`